# Swift Bezierpath doesnt response after addLine Method

Tags: ios, swift, view, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw of my view with using bezierPath and my code is ?

```
    class auctionCollectionView : UIView{
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    
private var shapeLayer: CALayer?


private func addShape() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = mys2().cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
     
    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    
    let colorTop =  UIColor(hexFromString: "#101820").cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(hexFromString: "#101820").cgColor
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = mys2().bounds
         
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
}
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.addShape()
    
}
func mys2() -> UIBezierPath {
  
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height/4)) // start top left
    path.addQuadCurve(to:  CGPoint(x: self.frame.width , y:self.frame.height/4), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 , y: 0 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height * 3/4))
    
    path.addQuadCurve(to:  CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height * 3/4), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height / 2))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height/4))
    path.close()
    return path
 }
}
```

And the output is looks like [image]

My first QuadCurve looks ok but when I try to add this to from `maxX (self.frame.width)` , `maxY ( self.frame.height * 3/4)` to `minX ( 0)` , `maxY (self.frame.height * 3/4)` with `CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height / 2)` it acts like adding line

What did I missing here ? Regards!

Comment: ...I'll just take a wild stab in the dark here and say that your question is being downvoted and marked to be closed because you forgot to a description on a desired result. It is somewhat clear from the code but you should still add something like "Expected result is that bottom part is not a straight line but a curve similar  to the top. Also a gradient should display instead of black color."

Comment: I understood . I asked this question so quick so. I forgot to explain details but your answer is currect.Thanks anyway @MaticOblak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path seems to be OK but I am worried your problem is what you call when overriding `draw` method.

You should either add layers once and manage them later. Or you should use draw rect to draw everything without using layers. In this case I suggest the second one. I am not exactly sure how your full implementation should be but from copying your path and seeing the gradient code it might be something similar to this:

```
@IBDesignable class DrawingView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor? = .red
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor? = .blue

    private func mys2() -> UIBezierPath {
      
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height/4)) // start top left
        path.addQuadCurve(to:  CGPoint(x: self.frame.width , y:self.frame.height/4), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 , y: 0 ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height * 3/4))
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to:  CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height * 3/4), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height/4))
        path.close()
        return path
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let topColor = topColor, let bottomColor = bottomColor else {
            return
        }
        
        // Save because of clipping
        context.saveGState()
        
        // Add clipping from my path
        mys2().addClip()
        
        let locations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
        let colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        if let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors as CFArray, locations: locations) {
            context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint.zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: frame.size.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        }
        
        context.restoreGState()
        
        
    }
    
}
```

So instead of mask we can just use clipping which is kind of what mask does in the first place in layer. The gradient code is a little bit different but still similar enough.

Now note that this method will be called whenever the view needs to redraw. To force a redraw you need to call `setNeedsDisplay`. So something like the following can be pretty common:

```
@IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor? = .red { didSet { refresh() } }
@IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor? = .blue { didSet { refresh() } }

override var frame: CGRect { didSet { refresh() } }

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    refresh()
}

private func refresh() { setNeedsDisplay() }
```

So basically you force it to redraw when:

- Any of the colors change
- Frame is being set (usual case when not using auto-layout)
- Subviews are being layout (usual case when using auto-layout)

Note that calling `setNeedsDisplay` will not force the reload instantly and call `draw` method. It just marks the component dirty and will redraw it in the next loop. The result is that `draw` will be called only once even if you call `setNeedsDisplay` multiple times in the same loop (stack, method...). So there are no performance issues.

The same can be done in your case with using layers. You need a `refresh` method whenever something changes. Then this method should either create sublayers or correct the sublayers frames, mask... And the `draw` method should be removed. So either use one or the other approach but not both.